# PandasでエクセルのISNA関数と同等の条件文を書くには？

Tags: python, pandas

少しややこしい質問ですが、isnaとifの複合文の書き方の質問です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

元データはABCD列のデータのみです。
セルE2のようなisnaの条件文を作りたいですが、

```
df = read_csv("file.csv",index_col=0)
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    if pd.isnull(r["city1"]):
        print(r)
    else:
        print(df.iloc[0,0])
```

```
354
354
354
354
354
```

と返した。

どう書き換えたらいいですか？
ご教授頂けると幸いです。

Comment: もしも forループで処理を行うのが前提なら, 質問内に理由示したほうがよいかも (一般的には `for`だと処理速度も遅くなり冗長になるので, pandasの機能使うはずなので)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> セルE2のようなisnaの条件文

たぶんこのような処理かもだけど, 質問はもう少し明確にしたほうがよいかも

```py
df.loc[1,'city1'] = df.loc[2,'city2'] = None
df.loc[3,'city1'] = df.loc[3,'city2'] = None

# nan 以外の最初のデータ
df['score'] = df.bfill(axis=1)['city1']
df
```

|  | city1 | city2 | city3 | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 354 | 533 | 657 | 354 |
| 1 | nan | 865 | 443 | 865 |
| 2 | 321 | nan | 997 | 321 |
| 3 | nan | nan | 902 | 902 |
| 4 | 743 | 321 | 431 | 743 |

---

**追記**
(コメントから)
'city3'のカラムも欠損している場合は, 現在の結果はこうなります

```py
df.loc[4,'city1'] = df.loc[4,'city2'] = df.loc[4,'city3'] = None

df['score'] = df.bfill(axis=1)['city1']
df
```

|  | city1 | city2 | city3 | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 354 | 533 | 657 | 354 |
| 1 | nan | 865 | 443 | 865 |
| 2 | 321 | nan | 997 | 321 |
| 3 | nan | nan | 902 | 902 |
| 4 | nan | nan | nan | nan |

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。もしcity3の列にnanがあれば、どう書き換えたらいいですか？

Comment: 「もしcity3の列にnanがあれば」の意味が明確でないけど, (この回答で行ってるように) `df.loc[4,'city3'] = None`とすれば `nan`にできます(結果はそれで確認できる)。`'city3'`の列が `nan`の場合の処理をどのようにするか？ という意味なら それは質問側の範疇なので

Answer (score 0):

Pandasにも `isna()` メソッドがあるようです。

参考:
[pandasで欠損値NaNが含まれているか判定、個数をカウント](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-nan-judge-count/)

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.DataFrame.lookup()` メソッドが利用できるのであれば、以下の様にできるのですが、

```py
df['score'] = df.lookup(df.index, df.notna().idxmax(axis=1))
```

Pandas 2.0.0 で削除されてしまいましたので、

[Indexing and selecting data — pandas 2.1.4 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup)

> Formerly this could be achieved with the dedicated `DataFrame.lookup` method which was deprecated in version 1.2.0 and removed in version 2.0.0.

`pandas.DataFrame.loc` を使います。

```py
df['score'] = [df.loc[*i] for i in df.notna().idxmax(axis=1).items()]
print(df)

#         city1  city2  city3  score
# 1月1日  354.0  533.0    NaN  354.0
# 1月2日    NaN  865.0  443.0  865.0
# 1月3日  321.0    NaN  997.0  321.0
# 1月4日    NaN    NaN  902.0  902.0
# 1月5日    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。実行してみましたが、エラーメッセージが出ました：
df['score'] = [df.loc[*i] for i in df.notna().idxmax(axis=1).items()]
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?
コンマを入れても同じエラーメッセージが出ました。どうすればいいですか？

Comment: こちらの環境は Python 3.11.6/Pandas 2.1.4 ですが、エラーは発生していません。もしかすると、それ以前の行でエラーになっているのかもしれません。